# php mysql Query returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a mysql database. When I log into phpmyadmin and run this query

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Lat BETWEEN 56.000 AND 57.454 AND Lng BETWEEN 80.3434 AND 83.345`

I get a few results as expected. However when I run the same Query using Php I get 0 results.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Lat BETWEEN '$minlat' AND '$mazlat' AND   Lng  BETWEEN  '$minlng' AND '$maxlng' ";`

Why is the Php code returning 0 results?

Comment: when you run $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Lat BETWEEN '56.000' AND '57.454' AND Lng BETWEEN '80.3434' AND '83.345'"; do you get any result?

Comment: $mazlat should be $maxlat ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your code without single clone. Like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Lat BETWEEN $minlat and $mazlat AND Lng BETWEEN $minlng and $maxlng";
```

Comment: It won't change anything.